# jQuery Keypad z-index issue with a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a jQuery modal dialog (see [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)) with an element that uses jQuery keypad ([link](http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html)). Firebug shows me that the keypad is coming up but ***behind*** the dialog. I tried using bgiframe() but it doesn't work. What could be wrong?

```
$('.dialog').find('#test').keypad();
$('#keypad-div').bgiframe();
```

keypad-div is the div that holds the keypad according to firebug.

Short version of keypad that shows up when the input area is clicked from Firebug:

```
<div id="keypad-div" class="" style="position: absolute; top: 118.517px; width: auto; left: 515.75px; display: block;">
<div class="keypad-row"> etc.
</div>
<div class="keypad-row"> etc.
</div>
<div class="keypad-row"> etc.
</div>
<div class="keypad-row"> etc.
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"/>
</div>
```

and the keypad entry input box:

```
<input id="test" class="hasKeypad" type="text" name="test" readonly=""/>
```

Comment: did you add JQuery file in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bgiframe()` is an IE6 fix (and only IE6; doesn't work on other browsers).

Did you tried to change the `z-index` property for `#keypad-div` to a higher value (like 9999) ?

Comment: Yup. That worked. Changing the z-index to a high value worked. Thanks!